# Where can I get an Infernus early in the game (before unlocking third island)

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-iv

I'd like to know where/if I can find an Infernus rather early in the game. I have unlocked the second (middle) island.

Is there a place more likely to spawn them or a mission that will make me acquire one at this stage?

**edit:**
playing PC version

Answer (score 1):

The only way to legitimately get the Infernus is

> by finishing the last mission [Bernie Crane](http://gta.wikia.com/Bernie_Crane) gives you. You get an orange Infernus as a present for all your services.

Only problem is that after you've lost the car, or it gets destroyed. You won't get another oppertunity to get it. So it's actually very rare.

However

> in [Grand Theft Auto: Episodes from Liberty City](http://gta.wikia.com/Grand_Theft_Auto:_Episodes_from_Liberty_City) the Infernus is a relatively common vehicle.

Comment: I've already finished the game once, a while ago, and I do remember that Infernus will spawn like many other vehicles *if you are driving one*, in the second and third islands. But I'm pretty sure I had gotten one (in fat many) before I got that cool orange one (which I also kept).

Comment: Yeah that's a normal in-game response in GTA. When you're driving a particular vehicle, hundreds of similar vehicles will appear. But as soon as you leave the vehicle to swap it for another one. They will all disappear in thin air. At least this is what I had :(